# Problema carga modal

Tags: php, javascript, bootstrap

Llevo tiempo con un problema en una de las páginas de mi aplicación web.. resulta que todo viene por el tema de los modal.. Tengo 3 llamadas, una para dar de alta un registro, otra para editar y otra para eliminar registro. Toqueteando el código hoy me he dado cuenta que la página carga con data-whatever en el button de añadir registro. Lo que no entiendo es por qué no me abre la página si no pongo data-whatever. Cuando lo pongo tampoco hay manera de que los datos del formulario añadir se guarden ya que tan solo coge el valor del whatever.

```html
<button type="button" 
class="btn btn-theme btn--icon" 
data-toggle="modal" 
title="Add lesson" 
data-target="#addModal" 
data-whatever="Edit lesson">
   <i class="zwicon-plus"></i>
</button>
    
<button type="button" 
class="btn btn-theme btn--icon" 
title="Edit lesson" 
data-toggle="modal" 
data-target="#editModal"
data-whatever="Edit lesson"
data-id="<?php echo $id;?>" 
data-id2="<?php echo $row['class_name'];?>" 
data-id3="<?php echo $estudiante; ?>">
   <i class="zwicon-edit-pencil"></i>
</button>

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

<button type="button" 
class="btn btn-theme btn--icon" 
data-toggle="modal" 
title="Delete lesson" 
data-target="#deleteModal"
data-whatever="Delete lesson"
data-id="<?php echo $id;?>"
data-id2="<?php echo $row['teacher_id'];?>">
   <i class="zwicon-trash"></i>
</button>
```

Los modal los llamo así:

```html
<div class="modal fade" 
id="addModal" 
tabindex="-1" 
role="dialog" 
aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" 
aria-hidden="true">
```

Y el script:

```
$('#addModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
  var recipient = button.data('whatever') // Extract info from data-* attributes
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-title').text('Operation: ' + recipient)
  modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient)
})

$('#editModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
  var recipient = button.data('whatever') // Extract info from data-* attributes
  var recipient1 = button.data('whatever1')
  var recipient2 = button.data('whatever2')
  var recipient3 = button.data('whatever3')
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-title').text(recipient)
  modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient)
})

$('#deleteModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
  var recipient = button.data('whatever') // Extract info from data-* attributes
  var id_lesson = button.data('id')
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find('.modal-title').text(recipient)
  modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient)
  modal.find('.modal-body #id_lesson').val(id_lesson)
  //modal.find('.modal-body input').val(id_lesson)
})
```

Comment: puedes agregar en si que es lo que buscas lograr pues no se entiende muy bien.

Comment: Perdona. Acabo de editar la pregunta. De todas formas el problema principal es que no me deja añadir registros por el valor que tiene data-whatever... si se lo quito ya no me carga la página